# How Do I Attach an ASG to an ALB Target Group?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

In AWS' Cloudformation, how do I attach an Autoscaling Group (ASG) to an Application Load Balancer Target Group?

There does not appear to be any direct way to do that directly in a Cloudformation Template (CFT), though it it possible using the AQWS CLI or API. The `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup` resource only offers these target types:

- `instance`. Targets are specified by instance ID.
- `ip`. Targets are specified by IP address.
- `lambda`. The target groups contains a single Lambda function.

Answer (score 15):

That is because, apparently, one does not attach an ASG to a target group; instead, one attaches a target group or groups to an ASG.

Seems a little backwards to me, but I'm sure it has to do with the ASG needing to register/deregister its instances as it scales in and out.

See the documentation for the [`AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-targetgrouparns) resource for details.

Example:

```
TargetGroup:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  Properties:
    VpcId: !Ref VPC
    TargetType: instance
    Port: 80
    Protocol: HTTP

AutoScalingGroup: 
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  Properties: 
    AvailabilityZones: !GetAZs !Ref "AWS::Region"
    MaxSize: "3"
    MinSize: "1"
    TargetGroupArns:
      - !Ref TargetGroup
```

Comment: And then how do you connect a target group with to ABL (AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer) ??

Comment: @juanp_1982 — One creates a *listener* (or listeners) within the ALB in question. Then, for that listener, one creates a rule (or rules) that forwards traffic to the target group in question.

Comment: I just Followed the above template but it is showing the instance in target group as `unused`. how can we change its status from `unused` to `healthy`???

Comment: Just to help other people the field name TargetGroupArns must be TargetGroupARNs with letter RN capitalize, wihtout this cause syntax error.